# Confused about the consistency of ZFC

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

Unfortunately I have never taken a class in mathematical logic. Shame on me. But I am reading here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC) that the consistency of the ZFC axioms is independent of the ZFC axioms itself.

But this tells me that ZFC must be consistent: indeed, suppose it was not, then there would exists a statement A such that both A and the negation of A can be justified in ZFC. But then ZFC would be inconsistent. Hence consistency of the ZFC axioms is not independent of ZFC, a contradiction.

Why is my justification wrong?

Comment: Read the opening of the article carefully: "The mathematical statements discussed below are provably independent of ZFC (the canonical axiomatic set theory of contemporary mathematics, consisting of the Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms plus the axiom of choice), **assuming that ZFC is consistent**."

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: Are you aware that a model of set theory (or for that matter arithmetic) may contain so-called non-standard elements? Your witness of inconsistency may well be non-standard. So the model may believe a proof of inconsistency exists, but being non-standard, it doesn’t correspond to a real proof.

Comment: My quibble with that article is that the consistency of ZFC belongs in the second section that starts with “existence of inaccessible cardinals” (i.e. statements that are independent of ZFC provided ZFC is consistent **and** provided they are consistent with ZFC).